# Find top 10% students in a class using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find top 10% (note its not top 10 its top 10%) students of a class.

My tries-

```
select *
From alphatable
LIMIT 0, (SELECT Floor(26*0.01))
```

But it is throwing error, let me know what I am doing wrong?

Fiddle- [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9fb0b/6)

**Edit**
Note- This is a dummy data..my actual class data contains 96 students..so let me know the formula of finding is correct or not?  `(count_student_number*.01)`

Comment: top 10 percent of what? which order?

Comment: you want top 10% on what basis ??

Comment: @rabudde top 10% of student having hightest scores

Comment: It would help if you mentioned WHAT error it is giving you, and what you were expecting.

Comment: @Arthur `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT Floor(26*0.01))' at line 3: select * From alphatable LIMIT 0, (SELECT Floor(26*0.01))`

Comment: where are the scores ??

Comment: @dianuj It is in the `fiddle` under occuerence table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following query and formula for finding top 10% students:

```
SELECT Floor(100 * 0.1) INTO @my_limit;
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM alphatable LIMIT ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @my_limit;
```

NOTE: Please add other required filters in query and also recheck your formula.

Answer (score 1):

Taking Samsonjet's answer into account try it like this:

```
SELECT FLOOR(
   (SELECT 10*(SELECT COUNT(*) 
               FROM alphatable)/100))
INTO @top_10_percent;
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * 
                   FROM alphatable 
                   ORDER BY occurnence LIMIT ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @top_10_percent;
```

It will calculate your top 10 percent by the given table and floor the result.

check your fiddle here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9fb0b/74